# How to loop this process until both initial times reach 0?

Tags: c++, loops

I've been trying to loop this process for a while using various types of loops: while, do-while, and for loops yet to no avail.

For context, one person would type in a group number that would have a corresponding number to be subtracted from the "initialTime1". After that, another person would do the same thing but would be subtracted from "initialTime2". I want this process to continue until both persons have 0 as their initialTime.

What would be the best type of loop to use and how to do it?

This is what I have so far using the while loop.

```
while ((initialTime1 > 0));
{
    if ((groupNumber1 == 1))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney1 += teensMoney)<<" and have "<< ( initialTime1 -= teensTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;   
        }
    else if ((groupNumber1 == 2))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney1 += familyMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime1 -= familyTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;  
        }       
    else if ((groupNumber1 == 3))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney1 += businessmenMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime1 -= businessmenTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;
        }
    else if ((groupNumber1 == 4 ))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney1 += seniorcitizensMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime1 -= seniorcitizensTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;
        }
    else if ((groupNumber1 == 5 ))
        {
        cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney1 += youngprofessionalsMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime1 -= youngprofessionalsTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;     
        }   
}

while ((initialTime2 > 0));
{
sleep(4);
system("CLS");

    cout<<name2<<", it is your turn. Choose what group to serve. \n" "Choose wisely. \n"
    "1 - A group of teenagers \n" 
    "2 - A family \n"
    "3 - A group of businessmen \n"
    "4 - A senior citizen couple \n"
    "5 - Young professional couple \n";

cout<<"Your choice:  ";
cin>>groupNumber2;
cout<<'\n';
cout<<"You chose group number "<<groupNumber2<<"."<<endl;
cout<<'\n'; 

    if ((groupNumber2 == 1))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney2 += teensMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime2 -= teensTime)<<" minutes remaining."<<endl;    
        }
    else if ((groupNumber2 == 2))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney2 += familyMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime2 -= familyTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;  
        }       
    else if ((groupNumber2 == 3))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney2 += businessmenMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime2 -= businessmenTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;
        }
    else if ((groupNumber2 == 4 ))
        {
            cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney2 += seniorcitizensMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime2 -= seniorcitizensTime)<<" minutes remaining."<<endl;
        }
    else if ((groupNumber2 == 5 ))
        {
        cout<<"You now have a total of "<<"$"<< (initialMoney2 += youngprofessionalsMoney) <<" and have "<< (initialTime2 -= youngprofessionalsTime) <<" minutes remaining."<<endl;     
        }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The best loop would be a `while` loop. Have you tried using `initialTime1 > 0 || initialTime2 > 0` as condition?

Comment: Yes, I already did try yet the program returns to 0 automatically after the first input on the 2nd person. It does not loop.

Comment: Then you have decreased both `initialTime1` and `initialTime2` to 0 or less in the first iteration.